# How does a slasher mower cut?

Tags: lawn-mower

There appear to be different types of mower cutters.  One which I've seen advertised is a "slasher mower" (this is an attachment for a tractor).

How does a slasher mower work?

(My Google-Fu is weak - I can't find anything specific on how they cut, and what differentiates them - other then that they are good for long grass, but do not cut fine - from the typical mower I'm familiar with - ie a spinning horizontal blade or 2 or 3)

Answer (score 1):

A slasher mower is used on rough areas where you just want to hack back the grass - it makes a messy job of it. There's also a flail mower, which does a tidier job and tends to cut the grass into smaller, mulch sized pieces, Both are usually used on large areas, with the flail more commonly used on, for instance, playing fields/sports fields which have become very overgrown (in the UK anyway). Further info here https://www.xmowing.com.au/the-difference-between-slashing-and-flail-mulching-mowing/

As for precisely how they cut, I can't answer that I'm afraid...